# Could BT mouses work without USB adapter that is included with them, if the PC already has BT built-in?

Tags: usb, mouse, bluetooth, dongle

I have a tablet with single USB port and I don't want to carry a USB hub with me,
so, I need a mouse that will work without using my single USB port.
My tablet has Bluetooth 4.0 built-in.

Ok, I found a mouse for myself: http://www.ebay.com/itm/iBUFFALO-Bluetooth4-0-BlueLED-mouse-with-USB-adapter-Silver-BSMBB09DSSV-New-/281530781966

And I like it, aside of one thing - it has some USB adapter included.
I asked the seller about that, and..., I think there are two options:
**The mouse does not work without that USB adapter**
or
**The seller does not know English well and answered as he can**.

My conversation with him:

```
Me: Hello.
 Could you tell if this mouse need it's own USB adapter inserted into PC's USB, even if the PC already has Bluetooth?
 I have a tablet with single USB port and I don't want to occupy it with mouse, so I need the one which will work without any USB adapters.
 Thank you.

Seller's answer: It has USB.

Me: Sorry, I asked not that.
 I asked if this mouse need to use own USB adapter that comes with mouse.
 I will try to show a scheme.
 Mouse <--------------> USB adapter <---> PC without Bluetooth = Working
 Mouse <--------------> PC with Bluetooth = Working?

Seller's answer: It cannot be use without the adapter.
```

But I think it's weird to write that this is BT mouse, if I can't use it with built-in BT, instead of that USB dongle from package.

Comment: Yes, it is similar frequency to bluetooth but it is not actual bluetooth, the dongle that plugs in is deigned to be recognised by the system as a HID or input device (and they work fine). Look for an actual BT input device that is not so cheap and does not come with a dongle, and specifially talks about pairing and all, or has users reviews. There are many BT input devices for laptops, tablets and phablets that will work with standard bluetooth.

Comment: @Psycogeek - But why they writes this is Bluetooth 4.0 mouse? It also has BT logo on the mouse... I don't want to give up my hope. I specially looking for BT 4.0 mouse and there are around only 5 of those in whole world :/

Comment: Oh i see, then they may very well use the actual protocol, that does not mean it would be designed to work with ever other BT. do not give up hope, find products that users have actually used the way you need them to.

Comment: That one is not a $7-14 mouse, and it does provide specs that indicate it uses standard BT, so time to look it up on the web.  is this Buffalo the company that also makes drive perefrials?  or Ibuffalo one more side product with an I in it to sound like other I products :-)  Were is the manufactures page?

Comment: @Psycogeek - That one: http://buffalo.jp/product/input/mouse/bsmbb09ds/ It has many BT logos... I now trying to find the User manual for it but it all in JP.

Comment: great, now google translate it and your all set.

Comment: Another clue, with all the OSes that it says it supports, there is no android support. Other BT input devices would also pair up with Iphones and androids built in BT.

Comment: @Psycogeek - ugh, it so confusing. Well, maybe that other devices does not support BT 4.0? I still trying to find the user manual. Google translator is very bad. It almost random words combinations.

Comment: @Psycogeek - I found the user manual, but it way too confusing to understand it fully. http://manual.buffalo.jp/buf-doc/supply/BSMBB09DS-300.pdf There is said that I need to plug that USB stick and install drivers "CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack" that are simply Bluetooth drivers... And then, I should pair Mouse with PC with standard procedure. But nowhere said that own USB stick is necessary or no, so, I think it impossible to tell. I think you should make an answer that says "it totally depends from mouse and it impossible to say exactly about that one"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bough this mouse and it works fine with built-in BT 4.0 of Windows 8.1 based tablet PC.